# How to decode this relocated call?

Tags: elf, disassembly, relocation

I am trying to learn a thing or two about assembly language by studying the instructions in some shared objects. I have encountered a construction where a `call` instruction leads to 1 byte after its beginning, for example (output from `hte`):

```
af6fc | e8fcffffff   call af6fdh
```

Clearly the destination address must be replaced by a proper function (which I know in this case is `strcmp`). I find this strange because in other parts of the *same* shared object the *same* `strcmp` function is called using the `.got` / `.plt` mechanism eliminating the need to rewrite parts of `.text`. In the latter case the destination function can be identified by studying the `.rel.plt` table along with `.dynsym`. But how do I find where the immediate address is redirected to in the former? I could not find any occurrence of the addresses `af6fc` or `af6fd` in any of the sections, at least not in those made accessible by `hte`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say which platform you are on. It appears to be `ix86`.

On `ix86`, it is possible to link non-`-fPIC` compiled code into a shared library (this produces a library with text relocations, which is suboptimal).

If you dump dynamic relocations with `objdump -R foo.so`, you should see that there is a relocation against address `0xaf6fd`. The dynamic linker will update 4 bytes at `0xaf6fd` to point to wherever the relocation tells it to after loading `foo.so`.

> in other parts of the same shared object the same strcmp function is called using the .got / .plt mechanism

These calls come from objects that were (properly) compiled with `-fPIC`.